# Как распарсить csv, в котором перевод строки есть в ячейке?

Tags: javascript, парсер, csv

Помогите пожалуйста распарсить csv. Я хотел бы использовать только средства нативного js. Вот моя попытка:

```
init();

function init() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '2.csv',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
      //console.log(data);
      csvParse(data);
    },
    error: function(textStatus) {
      console.log(textStatus);
    }
  });
};

function csvParse(data) {
  var temporaryArray = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);
  console.log(temporaryArray);
  var finalArray = [];

  temporaryArray.forEach(function(line) {
    var lineArr = line.split(';');
    finalArray.push(lineArr);
  })  

  console.log(finalArray);
}
```

То же самое в [песочнице](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y2Rm8mjZWjs62Lndf8Lp?p=preview).

Проблема в том, что я сначала разбиваю весь текст по символу перевода строки. Таким образом получаю массив, в каждом элементе которого есть перечисленные через знак ";" элементики.

Но в одной из ячеек csv-документа есть текст, в котором тоже используется передов строки. Поэтому вместо 11 элементов массива, я получаю 17. В этом проблема.